# How can I read property file at run time using NSIS script?

Tags: java, nsis

I have a *.property* file in my *Java* project. In that property file have more than 20 values. Now I want to parse that property file and change the specific property value at run time(that is when run the install file). I have used following code

```
Section
    ${ConfigWrite} "C:resource\conf.properties" SET WEBSERVICE.URL=http://localhost:8080 $R0
    ;$R0=CHANGED
SectionEnd
```

After running exe file ,the property added in property file like this

```
  SETSERVER.URL=http://localhost:8080
```

I don't know why the SET words comes before this variable?

My requirements:

1. I need to give value for ***SERVER.URL*** property at run time (while installing the *exe* file)?
2. I need to replace the value of ***SERVER.URL*** property.but Using above added one more new  property in that file.

I have used *NSIS plugin* in *Eclipse* on Windows platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some quotes when calling the macro, also there is no need to specify `SET` (in the example from help, `SET` is actually part of a command in a DOS batch file), and I guess that it is better to add a backslash to the path after the disk drive.

The doc states that the syntax is:

```
${ConfigWrite} "[File]" "[Entry]" "[Value]" $var
```

Therefore your call must be:

```
${ConfigWrite} "C:\resource\conf.properties" "WEBSERVICE.URL" "=http://localhost:8080" $0
```

Note how the parameters are splitted between the parameter name `WEBSERVICE.URL` and the value `=http://localhost:8080` (note the equal sign at the beginning).

You can make the directories dynamic too:

```
${ConfigWrite} "$INSTDIR\resource\conf.properties" "WEBSERVICE.URL" "=http://localhost:8080" $0
```

Comment: thanks.I think its working fine.but after installation WEBSERVICE.URL property value not yet replaced.still its remains old value.I dont know why?

Comment: @ILLA: did you tried a `MessageBox MB_OK "result=$0"` after the `ConfigWrite`? Does it tell that the setting was changed?

Comment: @ILLA: Sorry, but I do not understand what you mean. You ask about changing a value in a file. What is the "source path" you are mentioning? Also do you ask if you *need to* dynamically define the value, or if you *can* do it?

Comment: @seki.I have given source path.so its changed in source path only.I have hard coded the value of WEBSERVICE.URL.I need to give this value dynamically? Is it possible? also I donot know installation path then how do i give path name.still its replaced the source file property.

Comment: yes.I need to dynamically define the value.I have source path is my original java project.so i need two questions.1.define value dynamically 2.How i give installation path in {$configWrite}.

Comment: You are looking for something like `${ConfigWrite} "$INSTDIR\resource\conf.properties" ...`? If the path is not where the setup has just installed files, maybe that a `SearchPath` could help, or a `FindFirst`/`FindNext`? Or you could look for a value in the registry?

Comment: thats ok.what about 1(Define value dynamically)? any idea?

Comment: @ILLA: just replace the `$INSTDIR` by $1 in my second example, and compute $1 to the value that you need (read some registry file for example)